# Can php work with video files? If not, which language would be best?

Tags: php, video

Is there any Imagemagik like php-plugin that can work with video files (flv in particular) ? Id want to do things like save, size, and, hopefully, merge videos.

If php isnt the most practical approach, what language would be? It needs to be web compatible.

Comment: A scripting language + video editing == trouble.

Comment: I know im diving into something big here, but what would be the best language to allow simple video editing via a website?

Comment: Maybe something that isn't PHP. Any scripting language is bound to be slow as it is interpreted and not executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at [phpvideotoolkit](http://code.google.com/p/phpvideotoolkit/)? I believe this will be what you are looking for. It isn't a plugin but is a PHP Wrapper for video editing tools like [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/), [FLVTools2](http://www.inlet-media.de/flvtool2/) and [Mencoder](http://mplayerhq.hu).

EDIT:
Per the comments above these tools are mainly C / C++ which is much faster than PHP. The phpvideotoolkit wrapper will basically exec them from your PHP site which will be faster than manually using PHP to open a file and parse all the binary data.

Answer (score 1):

I've used `ffmpeg` in the past, and it's typically what I see recommended for any video processing as well.  I'm not sure how much it can do in terms of advanced video editing, but it's used for basic processing.

It's a command line program that you typically call through `exec`.

As far as I know, PHP has no built in video capabilities, but it can call other tools which do excel at this quite easily.